# Why can't I gain XP when I play on a dedicated server?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I'd like to play on Dedicated Servers, because I can get into the game faster and they offer overall better response times, not to mention that I can choose whatever map or game type I like.

But I have noticed, that if I play on them, I gain no experience and can't level up whatsoever. 
This is not the case when I click "Play", which is the old peer-to-peer hosting style.

What is the problem: Is this a feature or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So, which do you prefer? More fun games or prestiging, publicly? If I had the chance to play on ded. servers on the xbox, I'd give up prestiging for fun games. Currently, it's miserable. Well, unless you find firing first and dying 70% of the time "fun". =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is intended. in Modern Warfare 2 you could start the game twice, host a game and play "against yourself" to level up really fast (choosing a small map and directly killing the enemy on respawn). to avoid this type of "cheating", you won't gain XP on dedicated servers in MW3 (at least on PC, i don't know about X-Box and PS3 (if those have the possibility to have dedicated servers...)).

read more about that in [this article](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/10/23/modern-warfare-3s-dedicated-pc-servers-are-unranked-unlocks-co/), basically saying:

> "Public is about progression, private is about control."

Comment: The only way to play multiplayer on consoles is via matchmaking and the default servers - dedicated servers aren't an option there.

Comment: Couldn't this be solved by preventing two identical copies of MW3 from joining the same game? People could of course go out and buy multiple copies, but I don't see that being common, and to be honest getting XP does not give you that much of an edge. PC players already have to suffer hackers, I'd rather have the functionality and accept that the pre-existing balance problem would get slightly (trivially, even) worse.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't see why they couldn't just disallow the same player from joining twice.  This does not seem like a good reason to prevent XP gain in dedicated servers.  My guess would have been cheating, but even the "normal" networking mode doesn't prevent cheating, since they don't run anything on their servers (it's peer-to-peer).